# Make mssql fulltext search useful for enduser

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, containstable

I've implemented a fulltext search for one of our products. I'm using the `CONTAINS/CONTAINSTABLE` keyword for searching. But the problem is, that i often get syntax errors, because of wrong search conditions/input.

Is there a simple way to make the fulltext search enduser freandly, or do i have to build my own preparser before executing the search. For example splitting the search with a shunting yard and build a complete new search string?

It would be nice, if there is a more simple way, like SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere provides (They have a nice, robust fulltext search/index).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've previously used Michael Coles article "[A Google-like Full Text Search](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+(2008)/64248/)" to help me create a user friendly ASP.Net front-end to SQL Server FTS. The article goes into a good level of detail about how he uses Roman Ivantsov's Irony .NET Compiler Construction Kit to 'compile' a modified Google search syntax into a SQL Server FTS CONTAINS query. You don't have to understand it all though - there's a sample download that will get you going as long as you've got basic C# .Net skills.

I was very pleased with the result and the users were very pleased that they could do full text searches using a syntax they were already familiar with.

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: The only technology i feel at home is C#/.Net, so its perfect, thank you, i will read the article :)